# Update multiple text boxes in an Excel userform with data from variables

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I am looking for a way to update multiple text boxes in an Excel userform with data from a variable array. The text boxes are named as TextBox1, TextBox2 etc. And I want to update these text boxes in a DO LOOP rather than updating each text box line by line.

The variable array will contain n values for the n text boxes in the user form.

I am quite new to the user forms; Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try and customize this to fit your needs:

```
' Declare variables
Dim arrValues As Variant
Dim counter As Integer

' Initialize array
arrValues = Array("a", "b", "c")

' Loop through array items
For counter = 0 To UBound(arrValues)

    ' Refer to textboxes names from controls collections and assign array values
    Me.Controls("TextBox" & counter + 1).Text = arrValues(counter)

Next counter
```

Comment: Hi Ricardo, Thanks very much for your support. This is what I was looking for.